# MySQL returns only one result

Tags: mysql

This is my product table:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `idproduct` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `price` double unsigned NOT NULL,
  `shipping` double unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `condition` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `returns` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idproduct`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And this is my product_categories table

```
CREATE TABLE `products_subcategories` (
  `idproduct_category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idproduct` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `idsubcategory` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idproduct_category`),
  KEY `products_categories_products_idx` (`idproduct`),
  KEY `products_categories_categories_idx` (`idsubcategory`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_subcategories_products` FOREIGN KEY (`idproduct`) REFERENCES `products` (`idproduct`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `products_subcategories_subcategories` FOREIGN KEY (`idsubcategory`) REFERENCES `subcategories` (`idSubcategory`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I trying to search in products like that:

```
Select products.* from products 
  INNER JOIN products_subcategories 
    ON products.idproduct = products_subcategories.idproduct  
  WHERE name LIKE '%p%'
```

but it returns only one row.. without inner join it returns me more rows

Comment: use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

Comment: why do you have a `JOIN` when you're not selecting anything from the second table?

Comment: Why should every subcategory entry store  product id as well?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky one product may belong in many subcategories and one subcategory may have more than one products

Comment: @IleshPatel thank you, it worked, didn't believe that it was so simple :/

Comment: That is fine but then there should be another table that links categories and products. There shouldn't be a new entry for a sub category for every product. Its not normalized

Comment: @user3526572 That solution would return an identical result as omitting the JOIN altogether!